How to remove white flash from NET.MAUI Blazor app?
I was building a cross-platform app for a client, but this app required dark mode. But every time the user launched the app, they would get a blinding flash of white, which ruined the user experience tremendously, so I had to change technology to build the app.
Something else I notice is that the app comes with a default splashscreen with the .NET logo, but at no point during the application startup (at least on Windows) is the splashscreen shown.
I wouldn't be surprised if this was the problem, but now it would be: Why isn't the splashscreen shown on Windows?
As much as I searched, I couldn't find any solution to this issue, and I was left with too much doubt.This problem looks like this:
1 - App not started.
2 - Initializing app (This is the problem).
3 - Inizializing index.html (I changed the background color so that the states could be differentiated).
4 - App started.
I tried almost everything, from asking chatgpt, to going to Chinese programming forums, but I didn't find anything that could fix this problem, most likely it's something I didn't notice or some missing piece of code in my attempts to fix them. These are the things I tried:
1.1 - Change the background of the NET.MAUI application:
<!-- in App.xaml -->
<Style TargetType="ContentPage">
    <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="LightGray" />
</Style>

1.2
//in MainPage.xaml.cs
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    BackgroundColor = Colors.LightGray;
}

1.3
<!-- in MauiPage.xaml -->
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="MyApp.MainPage"
         BackgroundColor="LightBlue">
    <!-- Content -->
</ContentPage>

2 - Changing the background color of the application's WebView:
<!-- in MauiPage.xaml -->
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:GeoSynth"
         x:Class="GeoSynth.MainPage"
         BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource PageBackgroundColor}">

    <BlazorWebView BackgroundColor="LightGray" x:Name="blazorWebView" HostPage="wwwroot/index.html">
        <BlazorWebView.RootComponents>
            <RootComponent Selector="#app" ComponentType="{x:Type local:Components.Routes}" />
        </BlazorWebView.RootComponents>
    </BlazorWebView>
</ContentPage>

3 - Changing color from MauiProgram.cs:
    public static class MauiProgram
{
    public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
    {
        var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
        builder
            .UseMauiApp<App>()
            .ConfigureMauiHandlers(handlers =>
            {
                Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.WebViewHandler.Mapper
                .AppendToMapping("DefaultBackgroundColor", (handler, view) =>
                {
                    if (handler.PlatformView != null)
                    {
#if ANDROID
                        handler.PlatformView.SetBackgroundColor(
                            Android.Graphics.Color.Black
                        );
#elif IOS
                        handler.PlatformView.BackgroundColor = UIKit.UIColor.Black;
#elif WINDOWS
                        handler.PlatformView.DefaultBackgroundColor =
                        new Windows.UI.Color() { A = 255, R = 0, G = 0, B = 0 };
#endif
                    }
                });
            })
            .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
            {
                fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
            });

        builder.Services.AddMauiBlazorWebView();

#if DEBUG
        builder.Services.AddBlazorWebViewDeveloperTools();
        builder.Logging.AddDebug();
#endif

        return builder.Build();
    }
}

This is what I tried, but I couldn't get anything fixed.

WinUI 3 does not  have splash screen support.

@liyu Wow, you're driving me crazy, so how do I disable the splashscreen so it doesn't appear blank?

You can try changing the theme color of your desktop and keep it dark. When the program loads, it will first load the colors of the desktop. And it works.
